# bash regex in if statement

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, sh

I'm trying to add name-checking with regular expression, that passes only characters and digits but no special symbols given from the output. I wrote this code, but it's does not working. It shows "not ok" either when I'm typing only characters with digits or chars+special symbols

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/gm"
read -p "Type smth: " text

if [[ $text =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

Here's the output:

```
user@localhost:~/Documents/scripts$ ./testregex.sh
Type smth: hello$#!
not ok

user@localhost:~/Documents/scripts$ ./testregex.sh
Type smth: hello
not ok
```

Comment: Remove surrounding slashes and the `gm` option from your regex as `regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"`.

Comment: Your regex is actually Perl-style matching operator, not just a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
if [[ $text =~ ^[[:alnum:]_]+$ ]]
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:alnum:]_]+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `$` - end of string.

Note the absence of regex delimiter chars.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mWOfny).